# Convert Oracle PL/SQL Function to DB2 Function

Tags: oracle, plsql, db2

We have a Oracle PL/SQL function that is returning SYS_REFCURSOR, We want to translate this function to DB2 database.
Oracle Function:

```
create or replace function queryuser(p_tbname   in varchar2, p_user   in varchar2) 
return sys_refcursor 
is 
    l_cursor    sys_refcursor; 
    v_sql    varchar2(2000); 
begin 
    v_sql := 'select  productid  from ' || p_tbname || 'where user = :user' ; 
    open l_cursor for v_sql using p_user; 
    return l_cursor; 
end;
```

Pls advice me on how to translate this to DB2?

Answer (score 0):

According to the DB2 documentation they support Ref Cursor.  [Find out more](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053892.html).